# After Update Ubuntu Koha software has internal error

Tags: upgrade

I am facing an internal error in [Koha](http://koha-community.org/) software, which is a library software, after updating Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04.

What can I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: What internal error did you get? How did you install Koha? Using `apt`, or did you download the source?

Comment: @Shefali Pawar Please add to your question which commands you used to install and to run Koha, and the resulting errors. Please click [edit] to add those; please don't use Add Comment, but use [edit] instead.